# Weird behaviours in JQuery.ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The code below is part of an autocomplete input created using JQuery UI.
But my question here is related to the JQuery-AJAX part only.

```
change: function(event, ui){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/c_t_v_choices.php",
data: { filter: ui.item.value },
//dataType: "JSON",
}).done(function( msg ) {
    c_t_v_choices = msg;
    alert( "Data Saved: " + c_t_v_choices );
    $("#c_t_v").autocomplete("option", "source", c_t_v_choices);
});
```

The last line in the c_t_v.php file is:

```
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

The way the code is currently, I see valid data in the alert, sent by the php file. An example is shown below:

```
Data Saved: [{"label", "value"}, {"label", "value"}...]
```

However, when I enable the line:

```
dataType: "JSON",
```

I see something like:

```
Data Saved: [object: Object], [object: Object]
```

Why this weird behavior?

On a side note, any idea why $("#c_t_v").autocomplete is accepting the source i am providing in the code below (which is part of the code above):

```
$("#c_t_v").autocomplete("option", "source", c_t_v_choices);
```

Comment: Because it's turning the JSON into JSON, and JSON is objects.

Comment: Use console.log instead - it'll show you the children compared to alert.

Comment: `alert()` takes a string, it is not like a `var_dump()` in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data Saved: [{"label", "value"}, {"label", "value"}...]
```

Do a log on this data in this instance like this `console.log(typeof your_data_var)` -- is it a string?

When you specify JSON jQuery converts the returned json STRING into an object array so that you can easily access the json hierarchy using the dot notation, e.g. `Parent.child.something`.

It is the normal way jQuery handles JSON responses as it is more elegant and faster to lookup than using an array :)

PS In case you aren't I recommend you use `console.log`, and `console.dir` can be handy for arrays/objects and inspect with Firebug to get a better understanding of the object and what it contains.

Comment: When I 'watch' the variable 'msg' in Firebug, I get this output:"[{"label":"City1"},{"label":"City2"},{"label":"City3"},{"label":"City4"}]. Does this give any clue as to why the above behavior is occurring?

Comment: Also, would be very helpful if you can tell what do I need to to so that the final array is an array of objects, containing data of the following format: [{label: "City1"}, {label: "City2"}...]

Comment: You don't need to watch the variable, put a console log of the variable and inspect it in the console window of firebug. For the JSON to be a use-able object you specify dataType:"JSON" as you said. If you console log the data when doing that you will see it is a use-able object.